# JQuery: nested dialogs positioning

Tags: jquery, dialog

Is there a simple way to automatically position the overlapping nested dialog like this (suppose the blue dialog is created first, then the red one, then the yellow one), each time the dialog is created:

[image]

Comment: When you say "nested," do you really mean "one dialog inside of another?"

Comment: Could you clarify your question? As it is it is not so clear.

Comment: You are right Matt, they aren't actually nested. 'Child' dialogs are just opened by clicking on the button inside a 'parent' (the dialog which is already created) dialog. And they just spawn on the same exact place and overlap the parent completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by figuring out how many dialogs have already been created, before creating the new one, then using a multiplier on the left and top margin to correctly position the new dialog.

```
var currentDialogs = $("div.Dialog").length;
```

Next, when you create the new dialog, use the value to position it correctly:

```
$("<div class='Dialog' />").css({ 'margin-top': (currentDialogs * 20) + 'px', 'margin-left': (currentDialogs * 20) + 'px'}).appendTo("#theParentDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your nested div structure

```
<div class="a">
     <div class="b">
          <div class="c">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then create a class that shifts however much you want each box to shift.

```
.shift{
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;   
}
.a, .b, .c{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then with jquery add that class

```
$('.b').addClass('shift');
$('.c').addClass('shift');
```